# Is it possible to center an element using child element as center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element inside an element like this:

`<p>some text <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> some more text</p>`

Is it possible to center the `<p>` element with the `<i>` element as the center?

**EDIT:**

The text on both sides are not the same length

For clarification, this is what i am trying to achieve (Photoshopped)
[image: Clarification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add your text within another container you can try the solution below:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
}
p > span {
  width:100%;
}

p > span:first-child {
 text-align:right;
}

.centered {
  margin:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">

<p><span>some text</span> <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i><span> some more text</span></p>
<p><span>text</span> <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> <span>more </span></p>
```

Comment: For some reason it works in the snippet, but when i copy it to my document it is not?[image](https://gyazo.com/3a0c883dc2332293a821d1ca685cc39e)

Comment: @McMuffin sorry made a mistake, check again .. it should be width:100%

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Can you explain What and why is happening?

Comment: @McMuffin it's all about the shrink feature of flexbox. Initially I make the two span to be 100% width so equal in width but the total will exceed the container (200% + icons width > 100%) then flexbox will shrink all the item equally to avoid overflow so the span will have a width equal to 100% - X where X is the same for both so they will remain the same width (100% - X)

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

Add class `centered` to tag `<i>`

Sorry for bad spelling, I had nothing to work with.

**Run Code Snippet**

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <p>some text <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> some more text</p>
  <p> text <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> more text</p>
  <p> bardun <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> guyline</p>
  <p> ball <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> campfire</p>
  <p> knob <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> knot</p>
  <p> leder <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> scot Leader</p>
  <p> lejsss <i class="centered fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> campsite</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we are moving in the right direction, but it does not center the elements so that the `<i>` elements is displayed over [each other](https://gyazo.com/585d19a3c85d6a8b2c9c9e9c0c4fa153)

Comment: I guess that i haven't been as clear as i wanted. I have taken some more time and changed the image to exactly what i want. I see that you have centered the `<i>` elements and i will try to play around with your code to see if i can get what i want. Thanks